# JBoss two nodes cluster

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

As part of our internal product installation, I want to configure a two node Jboss standalone cluster and as per the documentation this is how jboss needs to be started :

\bin\standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -u  -Djgroups.bind_addr= -Djboss.node.name= -Djboss.server.base.dir=../

But I am not able to figure out what should I use for the multicast address and -Djgroups.bind_addr. Any way to find out this ?

Comment: Have you considered using a domain instead of two standalones? Using the HA profile (or full-ha in your case) makes the definition of clusters easy, and using a domain makes the servers' exploitation easier

Comment: @Aaron 16 Hello Aaron- Actually the application doesn't support the domain configuration. But for two clusters I will be using standalone-full-ha.xml (not standalone-full.xml).

Comment: yes, you should be using a profile containing ha components for clustering. Check the mod_cluster subsystem configuration to see which additional configuration you must provide.

Answer (score 0):

The "-b" option already specifies the default bind address of the server,  EAP does not use the "jgroups.bind_addr" property.
Additionally, JGroups does not allow "0.0.0.0" to be used as the bind address.  You should instead specify an actual interface address.

As for which multicast address to use, you can just use the default value, i.e. 230.0.0.4, or any address in the 224.0.0.0/4 range.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will try your suggestion.